# Convert a VB project to C# Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a fairly straight-forward question.

I have been working on a .NET web development project for about two weeks now, and I JUST got Visual Studio 2012 and I very much THOUGHT I had set it up to default to C# projects. Silly me.

I have not written a single solitary line of code yet, so when I finally roll up my sleeves and prepare to dive in to writing some code...I encounter the unpleasant surprise that I have developed the entire interface of the application without realizing this is a VB project, not a C# one.

I do not have ANY code to translate, I just want to know if there is a way to just change it over to C# without having to recreate the whole project in another file.

Comment: I've done this many times.  What do you mean by the development of the interface (even though you've not written any code)?

Comment: I mean I have laid out the web interface. The front end. The graphics, the layout, the CSS, the jQuery, the web forms. I haven't written any code on the back end yet.

Comment: You could fiddle with the vbproj files; I believe there are nodes that you can add/modify to change the "type" of the project. Is there any particular reason you can't just make a new project and copy over the static assets?

Comment: well, Asad, I just didn't know if there was a way to just turn a VB project into a C# project easily if there was no .NET code involved. That is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the work you've done is non .NET I recommend creating a new C# project and porting it over.

However I recommend:

- The VB.NET project is in source control and fully checked in
- You create a new C# project so you can work on them side-by-side

You can use a diff editor such as [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to ensure the important files are moved and are kept the same relative to each other.